# How to use a JavaScript variable in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print the value that the variable quantity holds in HTML

Here's my JavaScript code

```
class Ingredient {
  constructor (name, dateBought, expiryDate, quantity, expired){
    this.name = name;
    this.dateBought = dateBought;
    this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.expired = false;
  }
  isExpired(){
    this.expired = true;
  }
  needReorder(){
    console.log(this. name + "need to be reordered")
  }
}

let cabbage = ("cabbage", new Date(2003,3,2), 23)
```

I'm trying to display the quantity in an HTML file like this, so far nothing prints

```
<script src="inventory.js"> 
  
  var quantity = cabbage.quantity
  
</script>
<script>
    document.write(quantity)
</script>
```

I know that there isn't anything wrong with my HTML because this code works perfectly fine

```
<script>
   document.write("write something")
</script>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I updated the answer, please check. @RuijieLu

Comment: Please don't use document.write....

Comment: You can not have external source and inline script in the same tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use the variable `cabbage.quantity` in another script, not in the importing script.

```
<script src="inventory.js">   
</script>

<script>
    var quantity = cabbage.quantity
    document.write(quantity)
</script>
```

2. Missing the `new Ingredient` with 4th argument.

```
let cabbage = new Ingredient("cabbage", new Date(2003,3,2), 23, 50)
```

Comment: Can you explain? I tried document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = quantity; Is this correct?

Comment: correct. since script is already imported in html file, you can use the variable as you want like that.

Comment: just the important notice is that variable should be used not in the first script (importing script), but in another script.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Why is the 4th argument needed? I want to have expired defaulted as false, really confused

Comment: if you don't define the 4th argument, it will be undefined.

Comment: please check carefully, 4th argument is quantity in your class.

Comment: expired is the 5th argument.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `Ingredient` class correctly. In your class declaration, `quantity` is expected to be the 4th argument, so you should pass that as follows:

```
new Ingredient("cabbage", new Date(2003,3,2), 23, 10)
```

Complete code:

```js
class Ingredient {
  constructor (name, dateBought, expiryDate, quantity, expired){
    this.name = name;
    this.dateBought = dateBought;
    this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.expired = false;
  }
  isExpired(){
    this.expired = true;
  }
  needReorder(){
    console.log(this. name + "need to be reordered")
  }
}

let cabbage = new Ingredient("cabbage", new Date(2003,3,2), 23, 10)
document.write(cabbage.quantity)
```

Comment: I can't see the difference

Comment: @RuijieLu If you notice carefully, there are differences there, it accesses the class by passing the quantity as the 4th argument.